# Looker Studio Calculated Field Error, the query is not giving desired results

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am working in Google Looker Studio, where I have used a chart for visulaisation. In the metric section I have used the columns points_earned and points_redeemed. Now I want to create a new column that is points_outstaning using the above two columns. When I am using the formula points_earned - points_redeemed I am getting the right answer. But I want to display the data in a specific format if the points_outstanding is in negative I want to display 0 for that.

I have used different formulas to achieve the results but I am getting the correct answer:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN (points_earned - points_redeemed) < 0 THEN 0
  ELSE points_earned - points_redeemed
END


IF((points_earned - points_redeemed) < 0, 0, points_earned - points_redeemed)


MAX(points_earned - points_redeemed, 0)
```

Here's a example of the results I am getting:

```
points_earned   points_redeemed points_outstanding
1960    0   1960
1125    1485    1034
711 1148    476
624 0   624
600 0   600
543 1084    468
508 700 1058
```

Can someone help me out in this. As I am stuck with this thing and not able to achieve the results.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot showcasing the table when you are using the CASE-WHEN calculated field?!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yIcm3y4LwuQhxmnR7k8S2zuTXk-XdxUI/view?usp=sharing


Let me know if this could help.....

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/gVbd1rP.png your CASE-WHEN seems to be working good when the same numbers are fed via sheets. its prolly something else which could be causing this amiss!

Comment: Yes because when I am using points_earned-points_reedemed this formula it is working fine. Also note that I am using a custom query to fetch the data:

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TJeg7kSZkGmHjvGnUwMlmlSAzTIlsqxMba2iEm_rdpM/edit?usp=sharing